# When I run multiple Mathematica programs from terminal, are they supposed to use different Kernel?

Tags: kernel, contexts, scripting

Since I found that when I using notebook interface, I need to assign different kernels to different notebooks (if I want to run them at the same time), I wonder if I run those *.m files from terminal by calling MathKernel -script XXX.m, are they using the same kernel or different ones?

Thanks.

Comment: Different instances of the same kernel.

Comment: @ilian Thanks, so they are not actually in the same one, right? If I just run several XXX.m files, they will not interfere each other right?

Comment: They will be different processes, variables or definitions won't be shared between them.  They will not interfere with each other.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, now it's clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments by me and [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) into an answer, these will be running in different instances (separate processes) of the same kernel executable.

There is a related note in the documentation of the [`WolframScript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/WolframScript.html) interpreter,

> Each of the Wolfram Language scripts running concurrently starts its own kernel, with no shared variables or definitions. The number of the Wolfram Language scripts running in parallel may be subject to licensing limitation.

and the same applies when using the `-script` command line option of `WolframKernel`/`MathKernel`.